# BLE communication reverse engineer for a MI Electric Scooter?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering

I want to make an android wear watch app for a Mi Electric Scooter.

I have studied the matter and realised there are three major ways to achieve this.

First I can try reverse engineer an existing app that communicates with this scooter and figure out the messages. Tried it and it is really hard to get anything out of it.

Second I can try to eavesdrop to bluetooth communication and figure out the messages or third I can log the bluetooth communication on android in development mode.

I think third should be the easiest? 
Have anyone already done that for this scooter?

Since I would expect communication is encoded are there any standards how this messages are formatted usually?

I saw a library for BLE Headsets (apprantly they use same format) is there any format/library for this kind of devices?

Comment: Hello, gorgi have you found any solution for this?